# Enable particular validator in button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to disable the validators for text box. but in the button click its firing

**JS:**

```
$("#content_rbOneYear").click(function() {
  debugger;
  var test = document.getElementById('<%= txtOneYear.ClientID %>');
  var test2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtTwoYear.ClientID %>');
  ValidatorEnable(test, true);
  ValidatorEnable(test2, true);
  test.style.visibility = "visible";
  test2.style.visibility = "visible";
  $("#content_txtOneYear").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#content_txtTwoYear").prop('disabled', true);
});
$("#content_rbTwoYear").click(function() {
  debugger;
  var test = document.getElementById('<%= txtOneYear.ClientID %>');
  var test2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtTwoYear.ClientID %>');
  ValidatorEnable(test, false);
  ValidatorEnable(test2, true);
  test.style.visibility = "visible";
  test2.style.visibility = "visible";
  $("#content_txtOneYear").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#content_txtTwoYear").prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
  <th style="font-weight: normal">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbOneYear" Style="margin-right: 10px;" runat="server" Text="1 Year" GroupName="measurementSystem"></asp:RadioButton>
  </th>
  <th style="font-weight: normal">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOneYear" CssClass="clsPackage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validator1" ControlToValidate="txtOneYear" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
  </th>

</tr>
<tr>
  <th style="font-weight: normal">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbTwoYear" Style="margin-right: 10px;" Text="2 Year" runat="server" GroupName="measurementSystem"></asp:RadioButton>
  </th>
  <th style="font-weight: normal">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwoYear" CssClass="clsPackage" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validator2" ControlToValidate="txtTwoYear" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
  </th>

</tr>
```

in  the button click I specify the validation group as Group1. it is showing error message in both text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the clientID of the validators instead of the controls:
                    var test = document.getElementById('<%= validator1.ClientID %>'); 
                    var test2 = document.getElementById('<%= validator2.ClientID %>'); 
                    ValidatorEnable(test, false);
                    ValidatorEnable(test2, true);